# PHP Function call with AJAX - Update cookie

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, request

I'm currently trying to update my cookie in a online-store.
When the amount of a specific product in the store is updated, the cookie has to be updated and reload the page.

I'm trying to do this with a `onchange` event with `JQuery`.
I coded this as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "./DAO/WinkelwagenDAO.php",
            data: {function: "UpdateAantal", productId: productId, Aantal: aantal},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Succeeded!", data);
                //location.reload(); //To reload page 

            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log("Something went wrong in the AJAX-request: ", err);
            }
            });
        });
```

This works and is logging the correct things.

Now for my PHP-file I catch this event:

```
if (isset($_POST['function'])) {
    $action = $_POST['function'];
    switch ($action) {
        case 'UpdateAantal' :
            echo "\nAmount to change for ProductId: " . $_POST['productId'] . " use function: " . $_POST['function'] . " set amount to: " . $_POST['Aantal'];
            WinkelwagenDAO::UpdateAantal($_POST['productId']);
    }
}
```

Here the `UpdateAantal()`-function will be called which is defined inside this php_file. Therefore I have to include another PHP file to get access to some getters/setters. (I think there is also a problem here because when I do `include_once './Model/WinkelwagenItem.php';` it gives a warning that file is not found (Altough the `class/class/...` IS CORRECT). When I do a `File_exists` like in the code below it says that file DOES exist (a bit stuck here)

```
public static function UpdateAantal($productId) {
    if (file_exists('Model/WinkelwagenItem.php')) {
        //echo "\nFile that you wanted to import in winkelwagenDAO does exist!\n<br>";
        include_once 'Model/WinkelwagenItem.php';
    } else {
        //echo "File that you wanted to import in WinkelwagenDAO does NOT exist!";
    }

    echo "\nUpdateAantal function called";
    $Array = self::getWinkelwagenItems();

    echo $Array[0]->getProductId(); //HERE IT GOES WRONG

    if (isset($_COOKIE["winkelwagen"])) { //COOKIE EXISTS?
        $Array = self::getWinkelwagenItems();
        $index = 0; //positie bijhouden

        foreach ($Array as $product) {
            if ($productId == $Array[$index]->getProductId()) {
                //echo $productId . " == " . $Array[$index]->getProductId();

                $Array[$index]->setAantal($_POST['Aantal']);
                $SerializeArray = serialize($Array);
                setcookie("winkelwagen", $SerializeArray);

                break; //Quit if match
            } else {
                $index++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "This cookie did not exist";
    }
}`
```

This is what I get in the console (error at the bottom) :

[image: Console Logs from functions - Includes Error message]

Seems that it can not call the `->GetProductID()` because of the `include_once()` is probably not done right? However when I do include_once it gives warning that: no such file in directory, I already double checked this and file does exist. It says it DOES EXISTS when i use if (File_exists in php).

```
Source/Model/WinkelwagenItem -> Getters and setters
Source/DAO/WinkelwagenDAO -> UpdateAantal function
```

Can anyone help me out ? Been trying all day

Comment: You know you can access cookies with javascript (unless they are http-only) ?

Comment: Cookies are stored on the client, so you don't have  to hit the server to update a cookie.

Comment: how can I do this for my example?